# Редирект в .htaccess только для одного сайта

Tags: .htaccess, http, https, редирект

Необходимо сделать редирект с http на https как с www так и без www, но только для одного сайта, (у CMS Netcat .htaccess один для всех сайтов в системе)
Вот это работает отлично

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?(.+)$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://%1%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```

Но дает результат на все сайты, возникает вопрос: как в этом редиректе уточнить что нужно это правило только для test.ru?

Answer (score 0):

Строчка `RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC]` в вашем примере лишняя. Эта проверка дублируется следующей. Вместо `(.+)` нужно указать `test.ru`, чтобы редирект срабатывал не на все домены.

```
RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^(?:www\.)?test\.ru$ [NC]
RewriteRule ^ https://test.ru%{REQUEST_URI} [L,NE,R=301]
```